# TURN server not added in libjingle_peerconnection library

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, rational-team-concert

Iam using libjingle_peerconnection library for webrtc connection,

this is the init of rtc connection,  i works for the same network,
not for other networks

what i need to do for turn server to work???

```
func initalizeWebRTC() -> Void {

    RTCPeerConnectionFactory.initializeSSL()
    self.webRtcClient  = RTCPeerConnectionFactory.init()
    let stunServer = self.defaultStunServer()
    let turnServer = self.getTurn()
    let defaultConstraint = self.createDefaultConstraint()
    let array = [turnServer, stunServer]
    print(array)
    self.peerConnection = self.webRtcClient?.peerConnection(withICEServers: array, constraints: defaultConstraint, delegate: self)
    print(peerConnection)

    self.localVideoView.delegate = self
    self.remoteVideoView.delegate = self
    // webrtc initalized local rendering of video on
    self.addLocalMediaStrem()

}

func defaultStunServer() -> RTCICEServer {
    let url = URL.init(string: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302");
    let iceServer = RTCICEServer.init(uri: url, username: "", password: "")
    return iceServer!
}

func getTurn() -> RTCICEServer {
    let url = URL.init(string: "turn:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx");
    let iceServer = RTCICEServer.init(uri: url, username: "xxxx", password: "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    return iceServer!
}
```